# subclipse override and commit?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

using subclipse, how do i commit my older unchanged file over someone else's bodged-up newer version of the file?

i seem to remember there being an 'override and commit' option in older versions, or maybe that was another version control product...

cheers.

Comment: the only way i can figure at the moment is to make an arbitrary, non-effective change to my working copy, mark as merged and then commit. seems like a long way around...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like [ticket 761](http://subclipse.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=761), which means that feature may not be available anytime soon, I am afraid.
The ["Mark as Merged"](http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/subclipse/index.html#section7_0) is still the way to override changes.

Answer (score 2):

using subclipse:
in history view: mark all versions you want to get rid of (use ctrl to add select)
then right click and revert

then commit and you should have a new version without the unwanted versions

Answer (score 1):

Use subversive. It supports override and commit. I decided to pass from subeclipse to subversive properly due to the lack of this feature.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. @pstanton, you may have seen "override and commit" in subversive. Even I was searching for the same option in subclipse after a long time and got to know it's not subclipse by this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it that way:

- update everything (overwrite your unchanged old version)
- show history
- in history pick the version you want to switch back to
- right click: get content
- commit